# How do i calculate the number of CUDA threads being launched?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I have a CUDA card with :  Cuda Compute capability (3.5)  If i have a call such as <<<2000,512>>> , what are the number of iterations that occur within the kernel?  I thought it was (2000*512), but testing isn't proving this? I also want to confirm that the way I'm calculating the the variable is correct.

The situation is, within the kernel I am incrementing a passed global memory number based on the thread number :

```
  int thr = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
  worknumber = globalnumber + thr;
```

So, when I return back to the CPU, I want to know exactly how many increments there were so I can keep track so I don't repeat or skip numbers when I recall the kernel GPU to process my next set of numbers.

Edit :

```
__global__ void allin(uint64_t *lkey, const unsigned char *d_patfile)
{

    uint64_t kkey;
    int tmp;
    int thr = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    kkey = *lkey + thr;

if (thr > tmp) {
    tmp = thr;
    printf("%u \n", thr);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going to have to explain what you mean by iterations. CUDA isn't, by design, iterative in any way

Comment: when i say iterations, i mean how many times is the code within the kernel being run.  What are the total threads?  I am not entirely sure i have my naming conventions right when i say threads. The definition of iterations : "the repetition of a sequence of computer instructions a specified number of times or until a condition is met".  Isn't that kinda exactly what takes place?

Comment: Can you expand that code snippet into your kernel. I would guess you are seeing the effects of a memory race, but without seeing code it is impossible to say

Comment: Thank you. I added more code, and at the same time i realized the tmp wouldn't work via other threads.  But, like i said, i am trying to figure out the number of times the kernel runs processes the code.

Comment: Your kernel doesn't make sense from a c/c++ perspective.  You are not initializing `tmp` to any value before testing it in the `if` statement.  I would think the compiler would be throwing a warning about that.  The number of threads or "iterations" created by `<<<2000,512>>>` is indeed 2000*512.  `printf` from a cuda kernel has various limitations, so using it to validate that a large number of threads were launched probably won't work.

Comment: I still don't understand your question. You said that  " I thought it was (2000*512), but testing isn't proving this?". How are you testing the number of executing threads? None of the values calculated are being stored anywhere. Your kernel is using an unintialised variable to control the printing. If the printed output if your only way of judging, it is no wonder you are confused

Comment: If you want to prove the 2000*512 number to yourself, then create a single `__device__` global variable, initialize it to zero, then have each thread do `atomicAdd(&var, 1);`  After that, copy the variable back to host code and print it out.

Comment: Thank you thank you... Perfect.  Robert, would you create that in a form of an answer, and ill approve it..

Comment: and regarding the UN-initialized tmp, it is (int tmp=0;) in my code. I copied it wrong.  But, regardless, it wouldn't work anyway.  Ill go Robert Crovella's route.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you launch a kernel with the configuration `<<<X,Y>>>`, and you have not violated any rules of CUDA usage, then the number of threads launched will, in fact, be X*Y (or a suitable modification of that if we are talking about 2 or 3 dimensional threadblocks and/or grids, i.e. `X.x*X.y*X.z*Y.x*Y.y*Y.z` ).

`printf` from a CUDA kernel has various [limitations](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#limitations).  Therefore, generating a large amount of `printf` output from a CUDA kernel is generally unwise and probably not useful for validating the number of threads launched in a large grid.

If you want to keep track of the number of threads that actually get launched, you could use a global variable and have each thread atomically update it.  Something like this:

```
$ cat t848.cu
#include <stdio.h>

__device__ unsigned long long totThr = 0;

__global__ void mykernel(){

  atomicAdd(&totThr, 1);
}

int main(){

  mykernel<<<2000,512>>>();
  unsigned long long total;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&total, totThr, sizeof(unsigned long long));
  printf("Total threads counted: %lu\n", total);
}
$ nvcc -o t848 t848.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t848
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
Total threads counted: 1024000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that atomic operations may be relatively slow.  I wouldn't recommend making regular use of such a code for performance reasons.  But if you want to convince yourself of the number of threads launched, it should give the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, I am on a learning curve with GPU coding.  This would be for debugging and piece of mind only.  Thank you for a very well thought out answer.  Much appreciated!